# Draw on p5.js using mousedragged

Tags: javascript, drawing, p5.js

Below is the code from my p5.js sketch. Whenever I drag the mouse, I want the sketch to draw the line according to the mousedrag.

```
let N = 64;
let SCALE = 10;
let arr = [];

function Index (N,i,j) {
  return i + j * N;
}

function Render () {
  for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      let d = arr[Index(N,i,j)];
      fill(d);
      noStroke();
      square(i*SCALE,j*SCALE,SCALE);
    }
  }
}

function mouseDragged () {
  arr[Index(N,mouseX/SCALE,mouseY/SCALE)] += 100;
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(N*SCALE, N*SCALE);
  for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      arr.push(0);
    }
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  Render(N);
}
```

Following is the image of what I want :

[image]

But the result I am getting is :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript (as opposed to other languages) division will result in a `Number` type which can be a float unless constrained to integer division explicitly.

(This is a common issue if you were porting a sketch from Processing Java to p5.js for example (where Java would've handled int to int divison))

You can change:

```
  arr[Index(N,mouseX/SCALE,mouseY/SCALE)] += 100;
```

to

```
  arr[Index(N,floor(mouseX/SCALE),floor(mouseY/SCALE))] += 100;
```

demo:

```js
let N = 64;
let SCALE = 10;
let arr = new Array(N * N).fill(0);

function Index (N,i,j) {
  return i + j * N;
}

function Render () {
  for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      let d = arr[Index(N,i,j)];
      fill(d);
      noStroke();
      square(i*SCALE,j*SCALE,SCALE);
    }
  }
}

function mouseDragged () {
  arr[Index(N,floor(mouseX/SCALE),floor(mouseY/SCALE))] += 100;
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(N*SCALE, N*SCALE);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  Render(N);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.7.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```